# RailsAdmin doesn't correctly handles belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I am playing with RailsAdmin on Rails 4. And I have very simple case (two models, Event belongs to Idea).

**Code:**

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :idea

end
```

**Schema**

```
  create_table "events", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "location"
    t.integer  "idea_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "events", ["idea_id"], name: "index_events_on_idea_id"

  create_table "ideas", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "descrption"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

And I am seeing this. And I can't figure out why does it show both drop down to choose idea and additional numeric editbox?

[image].

Comment: You need to map the relationship on both models, as in `idea has_many events`.

Comment: @Damien: Thanks. It works. Can you post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Great! Sure, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RailsAdmin` heavily relies on your relationships to dynamically generate the forms. Aside from that, you would have encountered other issues down the line if you didn't map your relationships from both models.

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  # missing
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :idea
end
```